# Reorder selection of files

Tags: vba, excel

I have created an Excel Macro at work to be used for assembling consolidated reports in Excel. The macro allows you to select a number of files, it then goes through those files and renames the first tab in each file (which with the way it is used is the only tab) to match the file name (so you can rename the files without having to open all and rename tabs), and then merges all these tabs into your current workbook, creating a large consolidated report.

However, I am running into the problem that the macro defaults to do this to the selected files in the alphabetical order of the file names, which then requires us to sort the tabs after we have run the macro.

What I am looking for is an adjustment to the macro that will sort the files by creation date&time, oldest to newest, because the order the files are created generally matches the desired result in our final reports.

I figure I will need to make a separate for i = 1 to etc loop that re-orders the selected files, store the new order, and use that order for the current loop, but I am not sure how to do that. I did to some searches, but while I found some similar items, anything similar seems to use a folder selection rather than individual file selection, and there were other differences I couldn't quite translate to my macro either. Here is the current macro:

```
Sub Reports()
Dim numberOfFilesChosen, i As Integer, Workbookname As String, tempFileDialog As FileDialog, mainWorkbook, sourceWorkbook As Workbook
Dim tempWorkSheet As Worksheet
Set mainWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Set tempFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
tempFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = True
numberOfFilesChosen = tempFileDialog.Show
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = 1 To tempFileDialog.SelectedItems.Count
Workbooks.Open tempFileDialog.SelectedItems(i)
    Set sourceWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
        With sourceWorkbook
        Workbookname = Left(.Name, InStr(.Name, ".") - 1)
        .Sheets(1).Name = Workbookname
        End With
    For Each tempWorkSheet In sourceWorkbook.Worksheets
    tempWorkSheet.Copy after:=mainWorkbook.Sheets(mainWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
    Next tempWorkSheet
    sourceWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I hope you can help me, thank you!

Comment: When the dialog to select the files is open, have you tried sorting the files by Creation Date before you select them?

Comment: Didn't realize that would work, but it does... that is a great temporary solution, and I will make sure to include that into my instructions for the department. I would still prefer something that forces the sort if possible, to prevent user error, but I can work with this as an immediate solution!

Comment: If you want the latest of the creation or last modified date, you can use the VBA `FileDateTime` function.  If you want only the creation date, you can use the `FileSystemObject` to obtain that. Then it's a matter of sorting, and looping through the sorted list of names instead of the list in the `.SelectedItems` property.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks for mentioning that! The FileDateTime  works nicely for me